# Year as Float to Datetime64

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a series of years in the following Series:

```
>>>temp
>>> 0          1994
1          1995
2          1996
3          -9999
4          1997
5          2001
dtype: float64
```

I have tried a number of different solutions to get these values to years. I only seem to be able to get the following to convert these floats to valid datetime values.

```
>>>temp.replace(-9999, np.nan).dropna().astype(int).astype(str).apply(np.datetime64)
>>>0   1994-01-01
1   1995-01-01
2   1996-01-01
4   2001-01-01
5   2002-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Is there a more effective way to go about this? I doubt that converting everything to an integer and then a string is actually necessary or appropriate in this circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print temp
0    1994
1    1995
2    1996
3   -9999
4    1997
5    2001
dtype: int64

print pd.to_datetime(temp, format='%Y', errors='coerce')
0   1994-01-01
1   1995-01-01
2   1996-01-01
3          NaT
4   1997-01-01
5   2001-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And if you need remove `NaT` add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
print pd.to_datetime(temp, format='%Y', errors='coerce').dropna()
0   1994-01-01
1   1995-01-01
2   1996-01-01
4   1997-01-01
5   2001-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard datetime library:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str(temp[1]),'%Y')
```

but needs to iterate over the Series, and manage errors, as it will crash on -9999

Something like this, will do the trick:

```
for i in range(1,len(temp)+1):
    try:
        temp[i]=datetime.datetime.strptime(str(temp[i]),'%Y')
    except:
        temp[i]=None
```